# Can you compute sup norms between polynomials on the computer?

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods

Can you compute sup norms between polynomials on the computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah Polynomial-Polynomial = Polynomial. Now take the derivative (which is possible for polynomials on a computer), search for the zeroes, plug those values in the function, check the boundaries and take the maximum of all those values.